# CSS: background-images base

Tags: css

Is it possible to enter a base tag/declaration in CSS, something like in HTML?
I need one because I use mod_rewrite and the url looks like that: domain.com/path/to/something/

So my background images aren't loading right (just index/home-page). All I can think of is to add the whole domain (which I have to change every time I update CSS on my webspace) but that I won't like to do.

Comment: Aren't your images in your css relative URLs?  If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the CSS in a style sheet, the paths are relative to the location of the style sheet file, not relative to the page.

For example, if you have a style sheet at `/css/global.css` and an image at `/images/logo.gif`, you would reference the style sheet from the page like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css" />
```

(Note that you use a path relative to the root, so that it doesn't matter what URL was used to request the page.)

In the style sheet you would use the image like this:

```
#Logo { background: url(../images/logo.gif); }
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a structure something like:

```
/index.html
/img
    /image1.png
    /image2.png
/css
    /styles.css
```

Move all your CSS rules into the external styles.css stylesheet.

Now, within the CSS, your image references are relative to the location **of the stylesheet** - so you can use relative URLs like `background-image: url(../img/image1.png);`

Finally, make sure that in your HTML code, you use an absolute URL to link your stylesheet - like:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

Using relative URLs within your CSS means you're free to move your stylesheets and background images into different folders - or even to a different domain or server - whilst the absolute URL `/css/styles.css` in your HTML LINK tag won't be affected by mod_rewrite or anything else that affects your pages' apparent location on your server.

Answer (score -1):

If you can, you should anchor your URL's so they become `root relative`:

For instance, change:

```
background-image: url(images/image.png);
```

To this:

```
background-image: url(/images/image.png);
```

Secondly, even if your CSS was setup as a pure relative path, it is relative to the CSS file not the page (unless you are embedding the CSS in the page).

Answer (score -1):

The CSS is in a file and looks for example like this:

```
.ui-widget-content { background: black url(images/content.png) repeat-x; }
```

Structure:

```
domain.com/folderone/
domain.com/folderone/style/
domain.com/folderone/style/css/
domain.com/folderone/style/css/general.css
```

And a look on Firebug says that it's trying to load from:

> http://domain.com/style/css/images/content.png

Comment: This should not be posted as an answer - you should instead just edit your original post.